# vue.js table is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, scrollable

[this is my inputs page and i am using a table for products but the table is disorganized my design. it have to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShU3m.png) this my second attempt to add something here but i cant understant adding something here is edge of impossiblities. Always there is some errors this time mine codes are too much from text =/ ughhh

```js
new Vue({
el:"#app",
data:{
    users:[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Clementine Bauch",
        "username": "Samantha",
        "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
        "website": "ramiro.info",
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
        "username": "Karianne",
        "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
        "website": "kale.biz",
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
        "username": "Kamren",
        "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
        "website": "demarco.info",
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
        "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
        "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
        "website": "ola.org",
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
        "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
        "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
        "website": "elvis.io",
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
        "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
        "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
        "website": "jacynthe.com",
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Glenna Reichert",
        "username": "Delphine",
        "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
        "website": "conrad.com",
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
        "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
        "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
        "website": "ambrose.net",
      }
    ]
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
                <vs-table scroll overflow-hidden not-close auto-width
                v-model="selected"
                :total="totalItems"
                max-items="3"
                :data="users">
                <template slot="header">
                    <h3>
                    Users
                    </h3>
                </template>
                <template slot="thead">
                    <vs-th sort-key="email">
                    Email
                    </vs-th>
                    <vs-th sort-key="username">
                    Name
                    </vs-th>
                    <vs-th sort-key="website">
                    Website
                    </vs-th>
                    <vs-th sort-key="id">
                    Nro
                    </vs-th>
                </template>

                <template slot-scope="{data}" style="max-height=200px;">
                    <vs-tr maxHeight="200" :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" >
                    <vs-td :data="data[indextr].email">
                        {{data[indextr].email}}
                    </vs-td>

                    <vs-td :data="data[indextr].username">
                        {{data[indextr].username}}
                    </vs-td>

                    <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                        {{data[indextr].website}}
                    </vs-td>

                    <vs-td :data="data[indextr].id">
                        {{data[indextr].id}}
                    </vs-td>
                    </vs-tr>
                </template>
                </vs-table>

                <pre ref="pre"></pre>
            </div>
```

Comment: plz add a working pen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a height first, else your table will expand to the according with of it's content. Here mainly height and overflow-y do the trick.

Example-1: here the headers are not fixed means if you scroll down the header will be hidden.

```
table{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

And if you want to make headers fixed then just give the above css properties to that particular div/area. For example if you want to want only table body to be scrollable then  give above property to tbody.

Comment: thank you for your interest. I added this codes inside my style tags but still same

Comment: plz check by inspecting your table in browser if that properties are getting applied or not

Comment: yes it is. But i think the problem is tr lines is kind of block they are not seperating because also i didnt change the height even i give important